# Set user and password for rabbitmq on docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a rabbitmq docker container with default user and password but when I try to enter to the management plugin those credentials doesn't work

This is how I create the container:

```
docker run -d -P --hostname rabbit -p 5009:5672 -p 5010:15672 --name rabbitmq -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=pass -v /home/desarrollo/rabbitmq/data:/var/lib/rabbitmq rabbitmq:3.6.10-management
```

What am I doing wrong?,

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the issue, I ran the same command on my system and it works great and i am able to login also with `user` and `pass` on ip:5010

Comment: The problem is that when I try to enter to the admin web page the user and the password does not work

Comment: Even admin page works fine for me

Comment: I needed to add inside the container the guest user because it doesn't appear, later I remove container and image and execute the same command and only appears the guest user

Comment: I needed to remove the volume folder (/home/desarrollo/rabbitmq/data) and now the container is created with the user specified

Answer (score 1):

The default user is created only if the database does not exist. Therefore the environment variables have no effect if the volume already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to access in Chrome. Firefox worked fine. The culprit turned out to be a deprecated JS method that was no longer allowed by Chrome.